# bash exec set redirect use variable doesn't work

Tags: bash, shell

I want to open dozen of files. So I use the following script in bash :

```
for i in {20..30}
do
   touch $i
   exec $i>$i
done
```

but It does not work, because the `exec` can't use variable as `fd` to set redirection;

```
exec $i>$i # is incorrect, where $i is 20
exec 20>$i # is correct
```

BTW, the following scripts works:

```
for i in {20..30}
do
   touch $i
   eval exec $i\>\$i
done
```

Hope you can explain WHY ?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?  Why not just use `cat`?

Comment: This might be the first legitimate use of `eval` I've seen in a StackOverflow question.

Answer (score 0):

As per the [eval manpage](http://ss64.com/bash/eval.html),

> Syntax
>             eval [arguments]
>
> **The arguments are concatenated together into a single command**,
>   which is then read and executed, and its exit status returned as the
>   exit status of eval. If there are no arguments or only empty
>   arguments, the return status is zero.

`eval exec $i\>\$i` replaces the first `$i` with the number, the second `$i` is left as is because you have escaped the `$` in that case. So effectively you get `exec 2>$i` which is then executed.

<sub>**Note:** Use bash -x to execute and see what happens.</sub>

Comment: +1 I think escaping either dollar sign is optional; you'll get the same result whether either parameter `i` is expanded during the `eval` or the `exec`.

Answer (score 0):

> but why exec $i>$i not works ?

The Open Group Base Specifications Issue 7, chapter 2. Shell Command Language, section [2.7 Redirection](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_07) says:

> The redirection operators can be preceded by one or more digits (with
>   no intervening  characters allowed) to designate the file
>   descriptor number.
>
> If the redirection operator is "<<" or "<<-", the word that follows
>   the redirection operator shall be subjected to quote removal; it is
>   unspecified whether any of the other expansions occur. For the other
>   redirection operators, the word that follows the redirection operator
>   shall be subjected to tilde expansion, parameter expansion, command
>   substitution, arithmetic expansion, and quote removal.

Although it is not explicitly stated, the fact that parameter expansion is mentioned only for the word that follows the redirection operator suggests that this expansion is not applied to what precedes redirection operators.